# Serverspec fails to verify any package installed by pip on OS X target

Tags: macos, serverspec

Using `serverspec-2.36.0` I cannot verify any package installed by `pip` on OS X El Capitan virtual machine.

Testing the command executed by Serverspec gives correct results.

The following example is for `ansible` installed with `pip install ansible --user` on user `vagrant`.

- My `ansible_spec.rb`:

  ```
  require 'spec_helper'

  describe command('whoami') do
    let(:disable_sudo) { true }
    its(:stdout) { should match 'vagrant' }
  end

  describe package('ansible') do
    let(:disable_sudo) { true }
    it { should be_installed.by('pip') }
  end
  ```
- Result:

  ```
  Command "whoami"
    stdout
      should match "vagrant"

  Package "ansible"
    should be installed by "pip" (FAILED - 1)
  ```

  Details of the second task:

  ```
  Failures:

    1) Package "ansible" should be installed by "pip"
       On host `osx-01'
       Failure/Error: it { should be_installed.by('pip') }
         expected Package "ansible" to be installed by "pip"
         /bin/sh -c pip\ list\ \|\ grep\ -iw\ --\ \\\^ansible

       # ./spec/ansible_spec.rb:10:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
  ```
- I login to machine and run:

  ```
  $ whoami
  vagrant
  $ pip list | grep -iw -- ^ansible
  ansible (2.1.0.0)
  $ /bin/sh -c pip\ list\ \|\ grep\ -iw\ --\ \\\^ansible
  ansible (2.1.0.0)
  ```

I am clueless regarding both: the reason and next possible steps in troubleshooting.

---

**troubleshooting**

- I added a task to check `which python` (from inside the Serverspec) and it fails with:

  ```
  1) Command "which python" stdout should match "/usr/local/bin/python"
     On host `ansible-osx-devops-environment-01'
     Failure/Error: its(:stdout) { should match '/usr/local/bin/python' }
       expected "" to match "/usr/local/bin/python"
       env PATH="/usr/local/bin" /bin/sh -c which\ python

     # ./spec/ansible_spec.rb:11:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
  ```

Comment: Those backslashes are for escaping and the actual command is `pip list | grep -iw -- ^ansible` (https://github.com/mizzy/specinfra/blob/513a2c41c0d0f59ffd76f2308dffeabcfa8aadc8/lib/specinfra/command/base/package.rb#L40). Same output though. Interesting side effect is that command would also return a false success for, say, `ansible-lint` despite an absence of `ansible`. Anyway, this sounds like more of a vagrant issue than servserspec issue.

Comment: Well spotted `-w`! And it will in fact prevent ever finding `ansible-lint`.

Comment: Yeah, sorry I couldn't really help, but I am going to do a PR to Specinfra because of this. It is likely happening for other package providers too. By the way, have you tried this: https://github.com/jvoorhis/vagrant-serverspec? I have never used it, but it certainly looks promising.

Comment: I think I'm on track. For some reason Serverspec does not find `pip` (even `which pip` with explicitly provided `PATH` fails).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For reasons beyond my understanding Serverspec could not find either OS X's native Python (in `/usr/bin/python`) or the one installed with Homebrew (in `/usr/local/bin/python`).

As a workaround I added:

```
set :path, '/usr/local/bin:$PATH'
```

to `spec_helper.rb`.